# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Customers#show

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models one is customer.rb and second is money.rb.
The relationships are  customer has_many :money while money belongs_to customer. I am using MySql Remote Database. When i try to extract data from single table at a time it just work fine, but the problem is when i try to do this:

```
<%= @customer.money.each do |m| %>
  <%= m.id %>
  <%= m.cid %>
<% end %>
```

It throws an error: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'money_tb.customer_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `money_tb`.* FROM `money_tb` WHERE `money_tb`.`customer_id` = ?
Here is a snippet of my show.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= @customer.name %></h1>
<%= @customer.money.each do |m|  %>
  <%= @m.id %>
  <%= @m.cid %>
  <%= @m.customer.name %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my customers_controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @customers = Customer.all
    end

    def new
        @customer = Customer.new


    end
    def create
        @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
        if @customer.save
            flash[:notice] = "Customer Create"
            redirect_to new_customer_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end

    end

    def edit
        @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])

    end
    def update
        @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
        if @customer.update(customer_params)
            flash[:notice] = "Customer Updated"
            redirect_to customers_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
    def show
        @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    end
    private
    def customer_params
        params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :address, :ph_no)
    end



end
```

And this is the model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "cust_tb"
    has_many :money
    has_many :gold

end
```

Also i want to mention that customer_id field in money table is represented as "cid"

Answer (score 0):

If you have different foreign_key name than "association_name_id" then you need to pass `:foreign_key` option to both `belongs_to` and `has_many`.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :money, foreign_key: "cid"
end

class Money < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, foreign_key: "cid"
end
```